# How to compute rolling maximum or minimum of a dataframe column using dplyr subject to multiple conditions?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, max, min

Using dplyr I am trying to calculate a maximum value in each row of a dataframe column (dataframe = array), based on multiple conditions, but on a "rolling basis" as shown and described in the below image. By "rolling basis" I for purposes of calculations, the array is anchored at the top of the range (row 4) and extends to the current row where the calculation is occurring (and not the bottom of the array). The blue highlights show the dataframe created by running the below reproducible code, and the yellow highlights shows the values I am trying to recreate using dplyr with Excel code and explanations to the right.

Any recommendations for how to do this?

[image]

Below is my unsuccessful attempt to do this, using code that worked for the equivalent of `sumifs()` on a floating-array basis. But it doesn't work for `maxifs()`/`minifs()`.

```
library(dplyr)

myDF <- 
  data.frame(
    Names = c("R","R","B","R","X","X"),
    Group = c(0,1,1,2,2,0),
    Code1 = c(1,3,8,2,4,5)
  )

myDF %>% mutate(maxIfs = sapply(1:n(), function(x) max(Code1[1:x][(Names[1:x] == Names[x]) & (Group[1:x] == Group[x])])))
```

**Edit OP dplyr code to reflect the correction caught by cnbrownlie:**

```
myDF %>% mutate(maxIfs = sapply(1:n(), function(x) max(Code1[1:x][(Names[1:x] == Names[x]) & (Group[1:x] == 0)], 0)))
```

Comment: Your image doesn't seem to make sense to me, for the second row of the array for example, why is the rolling maximum 1 and not 3? i.e. the maximum value of Code in the first two rows, where Name = 'R' and Group = 1? This is what the R code is doing and is working as I would have expected

Comment: Is it because in the excel example you are requiring that the group value be 0? (that's what I put in my solution)..  As @cnbrownlie points out, the code you have written does what it is suppsed to do!.   A quick fix to match your image is to simply change the `Group[1:x]==Group[x]` to `Group[1:x]==0`.

Comment: Ah I see, the example R code posted is doing something different to the Excel, to replicate you would just look for where group is 0, right? `myDF %>% mutate(maxIfs = sapply(1:n(), function(x) max(Code1[1:x][(Names[1:x] == Names[x]) & (Group[1:x] == 0)], 0)))` (with the extra 0 to max to avoid getting `-Inf`)?

Comment: Yes exactly langtang! In my Excel example I threw in several conditions. One of those is group value = 0 from top of array to current row of array

Comment: Hi cnbrownlie, ahhhh I made yet another stupid mistake and you caught it. Here I go again, that's why I use the moniker Village.Idyot. Thank you and apologies for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach using data.table:

```
f <- function(d,i,n) {
  d[id<=i & Names==n & Group==0, if(.N>0) {max(Code1)} else {0}]
}

library(data.table)
setDT(myDF)

myDF[, id:=.I][,r_maxifs:=f(myDF, .BY$id, .BY$Names), .(id, Names)][,id:=NULL]
```

Output:

```
   Names Group Code1 r_maxifs
1:     R     0     1        1
2:     R     1     3        1
3:     B     1     8        0
4:     R     2     2        1
5:     X     2     4        0
6:     X     0     5        5
```